# How to fix 'bad interpreter' error when executing pip-related commands after changing username on an M1 MacBook?

Tags: python, macos, pip, apple-m1

I changed my username on the m1Pro MacBook, changing the original ht to haitao, and now I get the following error when executing pip-related commands:
{/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pyenv/2.3.17/pyenv.d/exec/pip-rehash/pip: /Users/haitao/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/ pip: /Users/ht/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory},
I tried google but didn't fix this error, can anyone help，I am not a native English speaker, please forgive me for the poor translation

I tried pip uninstall pip reloading pip but still got me with the error above, and I expect the pip command to work

Comment: there are some hard coded paths in `pip`. Since it is a brew install, could you simply reinstall. That should fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that all of your files used to be under `/Users/ht/`, but you've changed your username so they're now under `/Users/haitao/`. There are some things that're trying to find them using hard-coded paths, and therefore are still looking for them under `/Users/ht/`, and not finding them.

Specifically, from the error message "/Users/haitao/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/ pip: /Users/ht/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory", it looks like `pip` is a script (in `/Users/haitao/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/`) that starts with a shebang line saying to run it with the Python interpreter at `/Users/ht/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/python3.10`. Unfortunately, this is probably not the only file where there's a hard-coded path.

I see several options for fixing this:

- As FlyingTeller suggested, reinstall and force those files to be rebuilt with the new paths. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with homebrew and pip to know the exact process you'd have to go through to do this.
- Try to fix it "by hand", i.e. by editing the affected files. Be sure you have a good backup first (good policy anyway), because there's a significant chance of messing something else up in the process.

  You should be able to use a regular text editor to fix the shebang line in the `pip` script that's causing this error. Its first line will be something like:

  ```
  #!/Users/ht/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/python3.10
  ```

  Which needs to be changed to:

  ```
  #!/Users/haitao/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/python3.10
  ```

  There are probably other files that need fixing/updating; you can run `grep -r "/Users/ht/" ~/.pyenv` to get a list. Warning: they might not all be text files; if there are any non-text files that need fixing, you probably won't be able to fix them like this.
- I wouldn't recommend this, but you could create a symbolic link from your old home directory path to your new one. Something like `sudo ln -s haitao /Users/ht`. Then all the old paths would work, because they'd resolve via the symbolic link.

Comment: Nice answer. Is a symlink from `/Users/ht` to `/Users/hitao` maybe an option?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, that's essentially the same as my last suggestion. The only difference is that a relative symlink (to "haitao") will be more robust than an absolute one (to "/Users/haitao")... but the difference only matters in situations that're irrelevant here. So either one would work (but I'd prefer either of the first two options anyway).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last paragraph of your answer, so thanks for the extended explanation.

Comment: I had to uninstall pyenv due to rush to use, I now switch to conda to manage the python version, still appreciate your answer